# WCF service, The best overloaded method match for xxx has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, wcf

I've defined a class and using it in the WCF service and the client application, but when trying to compile the client I get the error, VS thinks it is a different class and can't convert to it, it was working a week ago and now with a new laptop I can't get the application to compile anymore... I'm afraid I've changed something, that I can't remember...

The error on the parameter is:

> Error 96  Argument 5: cannot convert from 'originalClass.Method[]' to 'Service.Method[]' ...

Comment: It is the exact same class used on both the service and client... but when calling a method from the client it sees it as different.

Comment: *I'm afraid I've changed something, that I can't remember* - do you not use source control?

Comment: It could be something as simple as regenerating your service reference against your service.

Comment: I do, but I'm thinking I changed something on files we don't upload like configuration files or project files

Comment: And yes, I've tried re-generating the services

Comment: One more detail I just found: the reference.cs file is now created with all the datacontract information. The original one has very generic definition of the service. Methods only not data contract

Comment: I would drop the service reference altogether an use ChannelFactory to connect to the service. It's much simpler.

Comment: Just following up on this... what was causing me problems was the Reference file it was spelling out all the definitions of the service as before I had a very generic file, I overwrote the new generated reference file and seems like it is working now. Not a long term solution but got me out of the hole.